# Erratic behavior between fadeOut() / fadeIn() plugin function calls

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm working on a site that uses fadeIn() and fadeOut() all the time, as transitions between different sections. For all scrollable divs, I'm using [NiceScroll plugin](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/).

The problem is that everytime I change the section I'm viewing - therefor using fadeOut() and fadeIn() - the plugin's jquery code stops working or works erratically. Another strange thing is that, if I open the browser inspector (I use Firefox), the plugin's code starts to work!

Here's an example of my code for some scrollable divs:

```
$('#Company_textContainer, #facebookContainer, .generic_textContainer').niceScroll({
    enablemousewheel: true,
    touchbehavior: true,
    cursoropacitymax: 0.6,
    cursorwidth: 8,
    scrollspeed: 60,
    mousescrollstep: 10,
    autohidemode: "hidden"
  });
```

HTML example:

```
<div class="generic_textContainer"">
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

CSS example:

```
.generic_textContainer {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 176px; height: 277px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 0%; right: 0%; bottom: 0%;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif; font-size: 14px; text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

They all work fine when shown **first**...

Help, please?

Pedro

Comment: Did you place the code in document ready?

Comment: Thank you for the swift response. Yes, I did - the niceScroll call is in document ready.

Comment: Are you sure the chaining works, what i mean is the 2id's and the class. Dont yuou have to call them separetely with each of them with thwir own nicescroll?

Comment: No - I tried that already and result is the same.